# Unit testing with using addAsync for deferred tasks in App Engine

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-app-engine

Is there a way I can force all calls to `addAsync` to complete?

```
@Test
public void aTest() throws Exception {
    SomeDeferredTask nextTask = new SomeDeferredTask();

    TaskOptions taskOptions = TaskOptions.Builder.withPayload(nextTask).
            etaMillis(1000).
            taskName("a-task-name");

    QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue().addAsync(taskOptions);

    LocalTaskQueue ltq = LocalTaskQueueTestConfig.getLocalTaskQueue();
    QueueStateInfo qsi = ltq.getQueueStateInfo().get(QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue().getQueueName());

    Assert.assertEquals(1, qsi.getTaskInfo().size());
}
```

I can't easily use the `Future` returned by `addAsync` as I also need to check for tasks creating tasks. Otherwise I could just do this:

```
    Future<TaskHandle> future = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue().addAsync(taskOptions);
    future.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

What I really need is a method to flush the queue of addAsync tasks and return when complete.

Is there anything to do this?

The only options I can see is to add all the returned futures to a static queue and write a method to ensure all those are completed before proceeding with my tests.

Answer (score 0):

> What I really need is a method to flush the queue of addAsync tasks and return when complete. Is there anything to do this?

I do not know of anything. I wrote a method like that for myself. It loops through all queued tasks calling `deserialize(taskInfo.getBodyAsBytes()).run()` on each whose deadline is passed. It's way more code that I'd wish for what seems a common scenario, but at the time I did not find a better solution. If you find anything else better, let me know!